# R: Object doesn't find custom function

Tags: r, oop

I'm newbie in R and I want to create an object with his methods. I have defined my object and function with these code:

```
setClass("gComparativa", slots=list(data="ANY"))
show_graphic <- function(object) 0
setGeneric("show_graphic")
setMethod("show_graphic", "gComparativa", function(object){
})
```

I create and call the method with these code:

```
g <- new("gComparativa", data=data)
g.show_graphic()
```

But when I call the method I've this error:

> Error in g.show_graphic() :    This function cannot be found
>   "g.show_graphic"

What am I doing wrong? What can I define methods and call later?

Comment: Might be other issues and I'm not the most familiar with S4 but you don't call methods in R with dot notation like that, you just do `show_graphic(g)`. See more here https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s4.html#s4-generics

Comment: @CalumYou Just saw your comment right after I posted my answer. I think technically your comment came first, so if you post as an answer I will delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need

```
show_graphic(g)
```

instead. R's OOP systems don't generally work like many other programming languages. ([Here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html)'s a good primer).

You can't access class functions via `<objectname>.<functionname>()`, but rather you just call the function on the object like `<functionname>(<objectname>)`.

Consider that dots can be part of an object name in R; for example try

```
example.object <- 2
example.object
# [1] 2
```